# Is there a way to build tabs inside a ContentPage in Xamarin

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a requirement to build a page presented in a picture. 
Please let me know is it possible to put **tabs inside a ContentPage** because I could't find any solutions online.
Any hint is appreciated :)
[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview

Comment: https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Tabs

Answer (score 0):

you can Xamarin Community ToolKit in which you can create the tabs on the content page. you can the position of the tabs by using the "TabStripPlacement" property

[CommunityToolKit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview)